# Content goes outside of div tag in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, overflow

I have a long single sentence in a div tag. This sentence goes out of the div tag when I am using IE8. In other browsers it is working fine. I have set `overflow:auto` in the div. It is just creating scroll bars which I do not want. I want the content to be adjusted in multiple lines based on the div size.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Overflow: auto will add a scroll bar.

What other tags are you using within the subject div?  Sounds like IE wants to render that element according to its box model.

It would be helpful to post a snippet of the code with the style information.

---

Edit 1:

As I expected, your culprit is the `<FIELDSET>` & `<LEGEND>` elements and how IE renders them versus other browsers.

This is a decent example of what IE is doing versus other browsers when using the fieldset tag:

http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/InForm/fieldset.htm

Not quite the answer you're looking for but a good starting point I hope.

---

Edit 2:

This link describes your exact problem and gives some very good insight on how to deal with it, enjoy!

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200905/line_wrapping_text_in_legend_elements/

Comment: <div id="NoLocationScreen" class="NoLocationScreen"  runat="server">   
                        <fieldset>                            
                            <h6 class="additional-info location-recomendation">
                             <legend id="JobsWithNoLocation">                                  
                                   <msc:Message ID="Message4" runat="server" DefaultText="This is my long sentence which is going out of div tag"></msc:Message>
                             </legend>
</h6></fieldset><div>

Comment: sorry for the format. i am new to stackoverflow. I ll learn to format.